# Getting error from expressjs while running as transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: html, express, content-type

I am running `expressjs` as a local server. I am getting the errors like this.. what is wrong here?

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/js/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css".
localhost/:11 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js".
localhost/:10 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js".
localhost/:12 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/js/scripts/app.js".
```

here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myNewApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> //i already declared the content type here.
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My New App!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my `server.js`:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

app

    .use(express.static( __dirname + 'public'));


app

    .get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile('public/main.html');
    })


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Why `app.get('*',...` instead of  `app.get('/',...`?

Comment: I guess both are same. `*` take care anything...

Comment: I don't think so. Try to replace it and see

Answer (score 0):

I moved my all `lib` assets to `public` directory. it works.